# Why do my SwiftUI gestures on a Map work only once?

Tags: ios, swiftui, gesture, geometryreader

**Setup:**

I am converting an app from UIKit to SwiftUI.
The app uses now instead of an `MKMapView` a SwiftUI `Map`.
Unfortunately, not all features of an `MKMapView` are already provided by Apple for `Map`, e.g. dragging a map annotation and getting the coordinate of the drag end point.
Anyway, I am trying thus to implement a similar function in SwiftUI. This is the development body of my annotation view:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in // 1
        let frameInGlobal = geo.frame(in: .global)
        Image("PinRed")
            .background(Color.green) // 2
            .offset(CGSize(width: dragAmount.width, height: dragAmount.height - liftOff)) // 3
            .defersSystemGestures(on: .all) // 4
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Global center: \(frameInGlobal.midX) x \(frameInGlobal.midY)")
            }
            .gesture(drag(frameInGlobal: frameInGlobal)) // 5
            .simultaneousGesture( // 6
                LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.2)
                    .onEnded { _ in // 7
                        liftOff = 40.0
                }
            )
    }
    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
    .background(Color.red) // 2
}
```

<1> `GeometryReader` is used to get the screen coordinates during dragging.
<2> The background colors are there so that it can easily be identified what happens.
<3> The pin image is offset by the drag amount plus a vertical shift so that the pin is visible above the finger.
<4> The system gestures, e.g. zoom in after double tap and long press to drag the map, are deferred so that the custom gestures come through.
<5> The custom drag gesture essentially changes a `@GestureState var dragAmount = CGSize.zero` so that the pin image follows the finger.
<6> A `simultaneousGesture` is required so that the custom tap gesture as well as the custom long press gesture can be used.
<7> That the pin is lift off, indicates that dragging can start.

**Problem:**

If the `liftOff` value is `0.0`, I can tap the annotation, which prints out its position, and I can long press it and drag it around. After dragging stopped, it still accepts further taps and long presses.
However, when the `liftOff` value is e.g. `40.0`, the annotation can only be tapped as long as it is not dragged, and when it has been dragged the 1st time, it cannot be dragged again. This means the custom gestures do no longer come through. Instead, only the system gestures work.
Here is an example of the situation after the 1st drag (green is the image background, red the `GeometryReader` background).

[image]

**Question:**

Why are the custom gestures only accepted when the pin is not lift off?
And how to do it right?

**Edit:**

I just found out that my custom gestures work **as long as `Image`** (green square) **and `GeometryReader`** (red square) **overlap**, and the tap point, long press point and start point of a drag are within the overlap area.

Comment: SwiftUI map has weird rendering behaviors additional drag gestures may not be compatible.

Comment: I would recommend to use MKMapView in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` than directly user SwiftUI Map

Comment: @Quang Hà You are surely right - I did so, and a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` `MKMapView` works fine. However, I am about learning SwiftUI and want to understand what's going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It has nothing to do with SwiftUI:
If in the code example above `liftOff` is `0`, the green `View` (`Image`) and the red `View` (`GeometryReader`) have always the same position on the screen. If the green `View` is tapped, the hit position is forwarded to the custom gestures. Since the red `View` has the same position on the screen, the red `View` handles the hit.
If however `liftOff` is larger than the `frame` size of the green and red `View`, both do not overlap on the screen. If now the green `View` is tapped, the hit position is forwarded to the red `View` that does not overlap the green `View`, i.e. the red `View` is not hit, and the hit is forwarded to the next `View` behind the green `View`, which is the `Map` itself. Thus the custom gestures are not triggered, but the system gestures.

In the code above, this can easily be checked by adding line 3 additionally as last view modifier of the `GeometryReader`.